# Drag formula and have it reference every other cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, z-index, offset

I have a simple if statement that I made that works. However, when I try to drag the formula so that it automatically populates the other cells, it doesn't reference the correct cells. That is because it increments the reference cell chronologically (i.e: goes from X to Y to Z) but I need it to increment every other cell (i.e: X to Z to AB) how would I do that?

Here is the snippet of the place where my formula is:

[image]

Here is a snippet of what I want it to reference:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you need an offset formula, but I'm finding it hard to follow what you are trying to do. Can you explain further? For example, in the second snippet it is not clear where your formula is and what the formula is trying to do.

Comment: re: '*i.e: X to Z to AA*' - did you mean i.e: X to Z to **AB** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get X3, Z3, AB3 etc by filling the following right.

```
=INDEX($X:$CP, ROW(3:3), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+1)
```

This makes your formula in CQ3,

```
=IF(INDEX($X:$CP, ROW(3:3), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+1)>1, 2, IF(INDEX($X:$CP, ROW(3:3), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+1)=1, 1, 0))
```

Fill down for row 4.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Could you explain the logic for me because I'm having a hard time following what its doing?

Comment: Use Evaluate Formula in the Review ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

you can just select the two cells before dragging and it will fill C1 by A1 and D1 by B1 :
[Excel generalization of two cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9x88.png)